# SilverStripe SAML infinite loading after SSO login

Tags: php, single-sign-on, saml-2.0, silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I have tried SilverStripe SAML module with azure ad single sign on, After enabled SAMLMiddleware Im redirecting infinite loop.

This is what saml.yml middleware part looks like

```
SilverStripe\Security\Security:
  properties:
    authenticators:
      default: %$SilverStripe\SAML\Authenticators\SAMLAuthenticator
SilverStripe\Control\Director:
  properties:
    Middlewares:
      SAMLMiddleware: %$SilverStripe\SAML\Middleware\SAMLMiddleware
SilverStripe\SAML\Middleware\SAMLMiddleware:
enabled: true
excluded_urls:
  - '/^dev/i'
  - '/^admin/i'
```

if some one have experinced this please help.
Thank you

Comment: Is your authentication passing on the iDP side , can you also enable the debug logs...

Comment: @AtmanirbharBharat When I test login with azure ad I can login, but in the log I can see POST request for 
/saml/acs this url gives a 302.